# OpenGL render loop - framerate / FPS too low

Tags: wpf, opengl, oculus

I have a window with an openGL view.
My window is WPF ; it contains a UserControl which contains the opengl context.

If I call continuously my render function (OnPaint() calls Refresh() at the end) then the framerate is 75 fps : it is my goal.
The problem is that the other events (mouse events, etc...) do not have enough time.
The application does not freeze but it is unusable.

I added a System::Timers::Timer in my UserControl. It calls Refresh() at 30 fps.
I tried with a CompositionTarget.Rendering event in the WPF : it calls UserControl.Invalidate() at 30 fps.

With these timers the application works fine with all events.
But they do not call my render function quick enough.

Is there a way to call my render function more often ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `System.Timers.Timer` may not be appropriate in this case. Switch to `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer` and give it a high priority like . [MSDN details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`DispatcherTimer` will also ensure that the call is coming from the same thread.

From MSDN link above:

> If a System.Timers.Timer is used in a WPF application, it is worth
>   noting that the System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread then
>   the user interface (UI) thread.
>
> Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer opposed to a
>   System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same
>   thread as the Dispatcher and a DispatcherPriority can be set on the
>   DispatcherTimer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Something odd : Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0); give real intervals 0 and sometimes 1. But Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1); give this kind of intervals : 8, 3, 10, 9, 15, 20, 5, ... For me, only interval=0 works.